# NSTableView ViewBased never calling the needed delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I have a NSTableView where I wish to display a list of info. 
Currently the `viewForTableColumn` method delegate never runs, but `numberOfRowsInTableView` does.

I have the NSTableViewDelegate and `NSTableViewDataSource` set in the ViewController head. And I set the tableview delegate and datasource to self. Does somebody know why it wouldn't run? I've added a screenshot and code below.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<App *> *installedApps;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _installedApps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;

    // Other stuff that populates the array
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return _installedApps.count;
}

-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"appCell" owner:self];
    result.textField.stringValue = @"Hello world";

    return result;
}
```

The view is in a container view, I have the 'appCell' identifier set to the Table Cell View.

[image: Screenshot of my storyboard]

Comment: BTW: You should use accessors. Use `self.installedApps` instead of `_installedApps` because the later might produce problems with KVO and subclassing.

Comment: Do you call `[self.tableView reloadData]` when fill your array?

Comment: Is `_tableView` `nil`?

Comment: @Willeke Nope not nil.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio Yep, it seems to know how many rows to make fine. It's just never calling the viewForTableColumn and displays blank cells.

Comment: @clemens Thanks, I'll start doing that from now on.

Comment: How did you check if `viewForTableColumn` is called? Is `textField` connected to Application name or Category?

Comment: @Willeke I have a break in the method and it should spit something out in the log. textField is connected to Application name.

Answer (score 0):

The array `_installedApps` is empty and `numberOfRowsInTableView:` returns 0. Thus, `tableView:viewForTableColumn:` is not called because there is no row to show. No rows also means no columns.

You should also ensure that you have configured your table view as *view based* in attributed inspector of the table view.

Comment: Even when I hard code a number in it still doesn't call tableView:viewForTableColumn:

Comment: @John: Is your table view configured as _view based_?

Comment: Also make sure _both_ of your delegates are connected. `numberOfRowsInTableView:` is an `NSTableViewDataSource` method, while `tableView:viewForTableColumn:` is a `NSTableViewDelegate` method. While both can be implemented by the same object, both of the table view outlets must be set to that object.

Comment: @JamesBucanek: Delegate and data source are connected correctly, see source code.

Comment: @clemens Oops/duh—I don't know how I missed that. I blame this flu. OK, if this is all of the code then there still might be at least one missing piece: `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`. If your table isn't using bindings, then I believe you're required to implement this data source method. While it's ostensibly superfluous if `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` gets all of its own data, I believe the framework still requires it and might simply refuse to function if not implemented.

Comment: @JamesBucanek I have it implemented but it also isn't called :/ Though I'm not sure what to actually return with that method, at the moment I just return a string.

Comment: Shot in the dark: If memory serves me—and it's been a while since I dug into the details—I think that if you define a prototype cell in IB then the programatic `viewFor...` methods are never called because the table creates the view instances for you. But I believe this also requires you configure the data source via bindings so there's an object to bind to the fields in the view (the cell view's `objectValue`). It might be worth revisiting the WWDC video on view-based tables (since none of this stuff seems to get formally documented these days).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it in the screenshots, but...is the highlighted row of the view hierarchy (Table Cell View) the one with the appCell identifier?

[minutes pass...]

Oops; sorry.  I see you've noted that above.

The reason I ask is that I made a new project from your code, changing the array type from App to NSString, added a one-column table view to the storyboard, linked it to the code, added a couple enties to the array in -viewDidLoad, and -- once I put the appCell identifier in the right place (duh) -- it all worked fine.

Comment: So where did you put the appCell identifier?

Comment: (Sorry for the delay.) The same place where you did: on the Table Cell View (class NSTableCellView). At first I had put it on the Table View Cell (class NSTextFieldCell).

Answer (score 0):

This is super strange, but I had the very same issue, everything connected correctly, number of rows being called, but not viewForTableColumn... In the end the following Answer proved to be the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091436/3963806

Basically, I had setup the tableview straight out of the Object library, no layout constraints etc... Once I added layout constraints, the method started to be called... Super strange as I could see and click on the "rows" but they weren't populated correctly... I think it's down to clipping as mention in the linked answer.